# How to toggle rxjs variable?

Tags: angular, rxjs

How correct is it to do a toggle variable?

```
public toggleLabels$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(true);

public toggleLabels() {
    this.toggleLabels$.next(!this.toggleLabels$.getValue());
}
```

I just get reverse value and push it back. Is it good way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [scan](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/scan) RxJS has a built in state managing solution that can be used for all state scenarios (also some that are more complex than a toggle mechanism).

> Useful for encapsulating and managing state. Applies an accumulator (or "reducer function") to each value from the source after an initial state is established -- either via a seed value (second argument), or from the first value from the source.

```js
const { Subject } = rxjs;
const { scan, startWith } = rxjs.operators;

const toggle$$ = new Subject();

const toggle$ = toggle$$.pipe(
  scan((state, curr) => !state, true),
  startWith(true)
);

toggle$.subscribe(console.log)

toggle$$.next()
toggle$$.next()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/7.4.0/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

*Bryan60* mentioned that my answer does not implement the behavior exactly as the question logic is. There are two conceptual differences:

- new subscriber wont get the last value
- no subscriber means the observable wont calculate/emit its pipe
  For both missing features there is a specific solution if needed:

**New subscriber (replay last value):**
The [shareReplay](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/shareReplay) operator allows you to share an observable and replay the last emitted value

> Share source and replay specified number of emissions on subscription.

**No subscriber (pipe wont emit):** [connectable](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/connectable) creates you an observable wich provides a `connect` method. This can be called to make your observable hot and subscribed. Then it will emit values without having a subscription.

**Info:** Both features (replaying and connecting) is most of the time not needed. In my last project we saw startup issues with an overuse of `BehaviorSubjects` and `multicasting`. If only one subscription happens a time and the subscription is done before values are emitted no replaying mechanism is needed. Please keep always in mind to only conscious implement features as the may have impact on startup-, runtime-performance or give your application an unexpected and incosistent behavior.

```js
const { Subject, connectable } = rxjs;
const { scan, startWith, shareReplay } = rxjs.operators;

const toggle$$ = new Subject();

const toggle$ = toggle$$.pipe(
  scan((state, curr) => !state, true),
  startWith(true),
  shareReplay(1)
);

connectable(toggle$).connect()

toggle$.subscribe(v => console.log("first subscribe: ", v))

toggle$$.next()
toggle$$.next()

toggle$.subscribe(v => console.log("second subscribe: ", v))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/7.4.0/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: there are some big flaws in this design that diverge from the original implementation. the state is new and unique to every subscriber, IE every subscriber will start with true and then alternate from there, regardless of what's happened before, so two subscribers could be getting opposite values depending on when they subscribe.

Comment: @bryan60 thanks for the hint. The shareReplay(1) operator will make the pipe hot and therefore the diff is "fixed" and also behaves like the BehaviorSubject implementation of the question. -> My main purpose was to show that scan allows you to handle state (like a toggle mechanism) in general. Sharing (making an observable hot) should be a conscious decision in an application as it has some small downsides in memory performance (personal experience in a project).

Comment: closer to the original, but still has one diff in that if the toggle is flipped prior to any subscriber, it won't register. the two subject set up I have is the only way I've ever been able to truly mimic a toggle like OP has originally. which is often what I really want

Comment: The question just asked for a correct implementation of a toggle variable in rxjs. Therefore the first not replaying and connected answer can be seen as valid, imo. But your points are important to consider (replaying, no subscriber case) and need to be considered when implementing pipes in general. In my experience the issue with "custom solutions" like using BehaviorSubjects and its replaying or BehaviorSubject and its getValue is that developers tend to mix rxjs with synchronuous/imperative programming. Therefore unexpected behaviors often get implemented and hard maintainable code is left.

Answer (score 0):

this is fine for something this simple but `getValue()` isn't something I'd make a habit of using. it can get messy and break in more complex situations.

you generally want to keep state modifications inside the observable to make sure everything happens in the order it's supposed to.

here's how you could do that:

```
// two subjects, one for saving state, one for signaling toggles
private toggleSource = new Subject();
private toggleLabelsSource = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(true);
// keep state observables private
toggleLabels$ = this.toggleLabelsSource.asObservable();

constructor() { 
  // link observables
  this.toggleSource.pipe(
    scan((toggle, _) => !toggle, true)
  ).subscribe(this.toggleLabels$);
}

public toggleLabels() {
  // call next on toggle signal.
  this.toggleSource.next(null);
}
```

this is overly complex for something so simple, but the pattern makes more sense when you're dealing with more complicated state transformations.

Answer (score 0):

Create a service that contains:

```
  private toggleValue = true;
  private toggleLabelsSource = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(this.toggleValue);
  currentToggleLabels = this.toggleLabelsSource.asObservable();


  toggleLabels(): void {
    this.toggleValue = !this.toggleValue;
    this.toggleLabelsSource.next(this.toggleValue);
  }
```

Then you can listen to `currentToggleLabels` and toggle through `toggleLabels()`

Comment: this works but it's functionally identical to using `getValue()` but has some extra steps

Comment: I think it is the easy and safe way to avoid future problem with `getValue()` and every property that need to be 'Encapsulation' is in `private` access.

Answer (score 0):

quick and dirty...

```
  show$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

  toggle() {
    this.show$.next(!this.show$.value);
  }
```